# How to adjust the image in sencha touch image panel?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Can any one help me to display image totally in the image panel.50% of the screen should display image and another 50% has some menus. In the 50% image block , I am not getting image fully. Here is my snippet.

```
Ext.define('scheduler.view.Main', {
        extend: Ext.Panel,
        xtype: 'main',
        config: {
            fullScreen: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            scrollable: true,
            cls: 'mainLayout',
            height: '100%',
            items: [
                {
                    cls: 'mainbackgpanl',
                    docked: 'top',
                    height: '50%'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'spacer'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        pack: 'center'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            width: '50%',
                            layout: {
                                pack: 'center'
                            },
                            ui: 'normal',
                            text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/calendar-icon.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Calendar</p></div>',
                            style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                            handler: function() {
                                scheduler.f.onCalendarTap();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            ui: 'normal',
                            width: '50%',
                            layout: {
                                pack: 'center'
                            },
                            text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/book-event.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Book Event</p></div>',
                            style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                            handler: function() {
                                scheduler.f.onBookEventTap();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'spacer'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            ui: 'normal',
                            width: '50%',
                            layout: {
                                pack: 'center'
                            },
                            text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/events.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Events</p></div>',
                            style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                            handler: function() {
                                scheduler.f.onEventsTap();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            ui: 'normal',
                            width: '50%',
                            layout: {
                                pack: 'center'
                            },
                            text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/blocked.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Blocked</p></div>',
                            style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                            handler: function() {
                                scheduler.f.onBlockedTap();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'spacer'
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

and here is my css

```
.mainbackgpanl > div{
         background: url("http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg") center ; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
         background-size:cover;
     }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to simplify your use case, I come up with this code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {      
        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: "fit",
            items: [{
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        ui: 'normal',
                        width: '50%',
                        layout: {
                            pack: 'center'
                        },
                        text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/events.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Events</p></div>',
                        style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                        handler: function() {
                            scheduler.f.onEventsTap();
                        }
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        ui: 'normal',
                        width: '50%',
                        layout: {
                            pack: 'center'
                        },
                        text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/blocked.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Blocked</p></div>',
                        style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                        handler: function() {
                            scheduler.f.onBlockedTap();
                        }
                    }]
            }]
        });

    }
});
```

Which apart from not loading the images (as I do not have them) it works fine, you can see a Sencha Fiddle [HERE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gra).

The main difference between my code and yours is that I have a parent panel with `layout: 'fit'` so that it takes up all the space available, then added the hbox layout in two child components below.

EDIT: If you are trying to make the images fill the containers so that they are both 50% width, you'll need to remove the height and width attributes `width="64px" height="64px"`. ExtJs has an [Image](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Img) component which may be better to use in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is, I need image(mentioned in cls mainbackgpanl ) 50% of the device, present which is not showing fully and another 50% should have modules with icons.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code actually works fine if you were to change `fullScreen` to `fullscreen`  have a look at the demo here

```
Ext.define('scheduler.view.Main', {
        extend: Ext.Panel,
        xtype: 'main',
        config: {
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            scrollable: true,
            cls: 'mainLayout',
            height: '100%',
            items: [{
                cls: 'mainbackgpanl',
                docked: 'top',
                height: '50%'
            }, {
                xtype: 'spacer'
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    pack: 'center'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    width: '50%',
                    layout: {
                        pack: 'center'
                    },
                    ui: 'normal',
                    text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/calendar-icon.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Calendar</p></div>',
                    style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                    handler: function() {
                        scheduler.f.onCalendarTap();
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'normal',
                    width: '50%',
                    layout: {
                        pack: 'center'
                    },
                    text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/book-event.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Book Event</p></div>',
                    style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                    handler: function() {
                        scheduler.f.onBookEventTap();
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'spacer'
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'normal',
                    width: '50%',
                    layout: {
                        pack: 'center'
                    },
                    text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/events.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Events</p></div>',
                    style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                    handler: function() {
                        scheduler.f.onEventsTap();
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'normal',
                    width: '50%',
                    layout: {
                        pack: 'center'
                    },
                    text: '<div align="center"><img width="64px" height="64px" src="resources/images/blocked.png"  style="vertical-align: middle"><br /><p class="icon_text">Blocked</p></div>',
                    style: 'background: none; border:none;',
                    handler: function() {
                        scheduler.f.onBlockedTap();
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'spacer'
            }]
        }
    });
```

Have a look at the demo here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gu5

Comment: Hi Rob, I changed the "fullscreen" but not getting image. In given fiddle, total image is not showing, bottom has been missed, tried with other images(http://www.utsavevents.com/uploads/1/0/4/0/10401165/4773833_orig.jpg) also. Is there any solution for this.